# Find minimum of tuple

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, tuples, minimum

I'm unable to get the minimum (the float in the example) of a list of tuples.  I converted them to an array and can't get the minimum there either.  I also want to sort the order.  I can't figure out how to do this.

```
[(' handicapped-infants', 0.4255567528735632),
 (' water-project-cost-sharing', 0.49741024814695456),
 (' adoption-of-the-budget-resolution', 0.25584421930900736),
 (' physician-fee-freeze', 0.05752597041257758),
 (' el-salvador-aid', 0.21445519728116716),
 (' religious-groups-in-schools', 0.3994529378797299),
 (' anti-satellite-test-ban', 0.37440262843488636)]
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. What are you asking about? Without context we can only guess. If this is python please add tag [python] and explicitly mention python in your question. If this is another programming language then please add a relevant tag and explicitly mention the language in your question. Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74243923/edit) button to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`list_of_tuples.sort(key=lambda t: t[1])`

Comment: Also `min_pair = min(list_of_tuples, key=lambda p: p[1])`

Answer (score 0):

I tried both answers and it still wouldn't work with a tuple.  I got "Tuple object has no attribute sort".  However, I converted it to a list using the code you suggested and it works.  I was able to get the list sorted and find the minimum pair.  Here's the code I used.

```
def impurities(df):
    a = []
    for f in features[1:]:
        a.append([f, impurity(df,f)])
        a.sort(key=lambda t: t[1])
    return a #(or a[0] for minimum)
impurities(df)
```